# stream out put to text file php centos

Tags: php, linux, stream, centos

i have follwoing code

```
<?php 


$handle = popen('rate -c 192.168.122.0/24 2>&1', 'r');
echo "$handle'; " . gettype($handle) . "\n";
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
echo $read;
pclose($handle);


?>
```

i want get the out put of this rate command to a text file its a third party tool to get the bandwith of the  but when i run the code i got follwing error

'Resource id #2'; resource sh: rate: command not found

but when i type rate command on my terminal i can see the out put

any ideas?

thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP can't find the rate program. The PATH envorinment variable does not contain the folder where rate resides.

Set the PATH environment variable with [putenv](http://php.net/putenv) or give the full path in your call.

Comment: thanks emil for reply yes you are correct any way i mange to give the correct path to rate command located then error message telling operation is not permitted

Comment: Do you try to run it through a web server or do you invoke PHP on the commandline? If as a web server, check that the web server user have permission to run the program.